# Looking for a regex to match an interior web page with an index page or not

Tags: regex, google-tag-manager

I have been charged with setting up a long list of triggers in Google Tag Manager for our sites. For some of these triggers regex seems to be the best solution, but I am new to this and really struggling with them. My current problem is matching an internal landing page. Here are examples of what should match:

- /interior/
- /interior/index.php
- /interior/?var=anything
- /interior/index.php?var=anything

It should NOT match:

- /interior/any-other-page(.php or not)
- /any-other-page(.php or not)

Here is what I built but it is not working:`^(\/interior\/(\?.*|index\.php(\?.*)?)?)$`

Thanks!

Comment: What is wrong with your pattern?

Comment: I am not totally sure what is wrong with the pattern, but it is not matching with GTM

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/KyuX8u/5 Your regex seems to work as is. Please provide more information as the problem seems to be elsewhere.

Comment: I also tested the pattern against the strings in the post and found no issues, hence my top comment question. Well, here is [a variation](https://regex101.com/r/cteCkH/1).

Answer (score 0):

My problem was in another Google Tag Manager setting and the trigger using that regex is now working. Thanks to everyone for their comments that pointed me in a different direction!